# Pronunciation problem

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english, subcontinental-english

I am from India. I am very eager to learn English. So I am used to add some English words with my language. But My friends says that you are having problem with your pronunciation. I tried a lot of times to pronounce well still I failed to pronounce. What should I do to pronounce English well? Kindly help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful, although your question may be off-topic there as well as here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving your English, which is off topic, as explained in our [help](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to subscribe to an English language phonetics podcast such as speakmoreclearly.com which offers a choice of accents: British, American and Australian. You'll learn in detail the proper position of tongue and lips in voiced and unvoiced vowels and consonants.